# comparing values in googlesheet columns

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW8qu.png)This is my first post on here. I'm not great at JavaScript, but I need it for some tasks at work.

if you look at the attached picture, i need the script to check the values in column Q to see if they match with the value in cell L6 AND check the values in Column R to see if they match values in column L. if BOTH of those conditions are met, the corresponding values in columns S and T need to be pasted into columns N and O.

It's basically to avoid manually having to search through tables to copy/paste values from one table to another. I hope the screenshot makes sense. The code below really just checks if the values in column Q match with the value in cell L7....but that's really all I can figure out right now...Please let me know!

```
function SearchCols() 
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"),
    searchVal = sheet.getRange("L:L7").getValue(),
    searchCol = sheet.getRange('Q11:Q').getValues();

    for (var i = 0, len = searchCol.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (searchCol[i][0] == searchVal) {
            sheet.getRange(i + 11, 15).setValue("Found Here")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Any effort? Show us your code.

Comment: all this does is check to see if values in column Q match with what's in cell L7 and then it'll paste 'Found here' in the column where I actually need the values from col S to go.

function SearchCols() 
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"),
        searchVal = sheet.getRange("L:L7").getValue(),
        searchCol = sheet.getRange('Q11:Q').getValues();
    for (var i = 0, len = searchCol.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (searchCol[i][0] == searchVal) {
          sheet.getRange(i + 11, 15).setValue("Found Here")
        }
    }
}

Comment: holy........that didn't paste well at all....

Comment: Better edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: does it look better now? so the problem is that the columns i'm comparing are of VARYING length...they're not equal like in my pic. is there a way to search down one column, then search down the other column to see where values match, and if there's a match, paste the required data into the required cells?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using Google spreadsheet formula. Add the below formula to your sheet.

**N11**: `=if(AND(Q11=$L$6,R11=L11),S11,"")` and then drag it till the required cell

**O11**: `=if(AND(Q11=$L$6,R11=L11),T11,"")` and then drag it till the required cell

[image]

Comment: this did work, yea. very cool.
is it possible to automate formulas like this into a BUTTON at all?
the thing is, I have like 30 sheets to go through, and i believe the columns in each sheet will be of varying length. can formulas be placed into buttons, so this can be achieved with 'the click of a button'?

Comment: the thing is, i made the tables equal in length. the problem is, they're NOT equal in length in my case. one table might be 10 times longer than the other table. so i was actually looking for a script that looks at the two tables, compares the cells to see if they match (it has to go down one column and see if the other column has matching values), and if matches are found, THEN copy/paste the adjacent values from one table to the other IF the 2 conditions above are met. do you understand?